# What is the difference between 就and 正好？

Tags: difference

I don't understand the difference yet. Please, tell me more about it!

Comment: Both have various meanings when used in various ways. Do you have example sentences that you are unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see some difference in the examples below. In translation 就正好 will not always be rendered as two words.

1. 好极了。那就正好。
   Fantastic! That's just right.
2. 车站就在前面，这条路就正好经过它。
   The station is straight ahead, this road leads right by it.
3. 如果你往树后更远处看，就正好可以看见远处的村庄。
   If you look beyond the trees, then (就) you can just (正好) see the village in the distance.
4. 在西方国家里习惯在垫褥里面填满很多的干草-因此这个意思就正好是说该上床睡觉了。
   In Western countries it was customary to fill mattresses with hay, thus the meaning then (就) (of hit the hay) was just (正好）to say "time for bed ".
5. 相反地，如果火开始灭了并且您将一大块原木放在熏烧的余烬上，那么原木就正好将火熄灭了。
   On the contrary, if if the fire is starting to go out and you place a log on the smouldering embers, well the log will then (就) just （正好） put out the fire.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your confusion is the timing of something to occur:

- 就, something **about** to happen. 他就要到機場了 - He is **about** to arrive at the airport.
- 正好, something **just** to happen. 他正好到機場了 - He **just** (in time) arrived at the airport.